# Ionic simple app not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a very simple app using Ionic, in order to learn how to use the tool. It implies tabs, I followed the tutorial about tabs given in the official documentation. It works very well on my browser, but I have the "blank screen of death" on my Android device when compiling.

Here is my simplified code:

Index.html

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
      </ion-tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Menu Principal">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <a href="#/tab/sceneTest"><img class="popphoto" src="b_menu1.png"></a>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
```

JS part:

```
  <script>
  angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('tabs', {
        url: "/tab",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
      })

      .state('tabs.home', {
        url: "/home",
        views: {
          'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tabs.sceneTest', {
        url: "/sceneTest",
         views: {
          'home-tab': {
            templateUrl: "sceneTest.html"
          }
        }
      })

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");
  })

  .controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
    console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

The "sceneTest.html" file is in the same path as index.html. I don't think it causes the bug, because its content is very simple so far (just a text wrapped in a ion-view).

Any idea of what may be causing the blank screen on mobile phones only? I have heard that it could be because of some inclusions I didn't do properly. However, I am very new to both Ionic and Angular (jQuery fan trying to open his mind) so it's hard to find the precise cause.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Call the files with in the App's www folder**

Wrong way

```
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```

Good Way

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```